# How can i use fsolve to plot the solutions to a function?

Tags: function, matlab, matlab-figure

I have a variable of a that is equal to (weight./(1360*pi)).^(1/3), where the weight ranges between 4 and 8kg.

I then have guess of the time taken ,which is 14400 seconds.

The function in question is attached, where infinity is replaced by k=22.
This function should be equal to 57/80

r/a can be replaced by 0.464, meaning that the multiplication of the summation can be written as 2/(0.464*pi).

alpha will be equal to 0.7*10^-7

How would i be able to plot the times taken for the masses to cook in hours, for weight in the given range?

I have tried to code this function for a couple of days now but it wont seem to work, due to array size issues and the general function just not working.

Comment: What is the value of `t` in the equation? What units does the equation return?

Comment: Sorry for not including this. The value of t is in seconds and so is the output of the equation.

Comment: What value of weight gives an output of 57/80?

Comment: Each value of the weight should be used in the function and be equal to 57/80. However, the value of t must be a specific value corresponding to the weight, in order for the function to be equal to 57/80, with this t value having to be found depending on the weight using fsolve. Do let me know if there are any other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a master equation as a function of weight and t, which you want `fsolve` to find the zero of. Then for each weight, you can capture it in another function that you then solve for t:

```
alpha = 0.7e-7;
rbya = 0.464;
k = 1:22;
a = @(weight)(weight./(1360*pi)).^(1/3);
eqn = @(weight,t)2/pi/rbya*sum((-1).^(k-1)./k.*sin(k*pi*rbya).*exp(-1.*k.^2.*pi^2.*alpha.*t./(a(weight).^2)))-57/80;

weights = 4:8;
ts = zeros(size(weights));
for i = 1:numel(weights)
    sub_eqn = @(t)eqn(weights(i),t);
    ts(i)=fsolve(sub_eqn,14400);
end

plot(weights,ts/(60*60))
xlabel("Weight (kg)")
ylabel("Cooking Time (hrs)")
```

If you want to solve the entire set of equations at once, then you need to be careful of array sizes (as you have experienced, read more [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html)). `k` should be a column vector so that `sum` will sum along each column, and `weights` should be a row vector so that element-wise operations will repeat the `k`’s for each weight. You also need your list of initial guesses to be the same size as `weights` so that `fsolve` can have a guess for each weight:

```
alpha = 0.7e-7;
rbya = 0.464;
k = (1:22)';

a = @(weight)(weight./(1360*pi)).^(1/3);

weights = 4:8;
eqn = @(t)2/pi/rbya*sum((-1).^(k-1)./k.*sin(k*pi*rbya).*exp(-1.*k.^2.*pi^2.*alpha.*t./(a(weights).^2)))-57/80;

ts=fsolve(eqn,repmat(14400,size(weights)));

plot(weights,ts/(60*60))
xlabel("Weight (kg)")
ylabel("Cooking Time (hrs)")
```

Note that you do get slightly different answers with the two methods.